# How does this answer not answer the question

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

This answer was deleted as not an answer.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/348701/17178

Why?

Answer (score -6):

Because this has been answered by somebody else in the comments.  The better course of action would have been to post another comment and prompt him to convert his comment into an answer.  Even better would be to recognize that this is an old repair question, and close-vote it.

*p.s.*  I've stumbled on your answer because of an automatic low quality flag.

Comment: Comments are not for answering.

Comment: Answers are not for taking credit for someone else's comments, @Passerby .

Comment: Yes they are https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins

Comment: As stated in the answer to Passerby's reference don't take credit yourself and put it up as a community wiki answer.